# Upgrade Angularjs 1.2.23 to 1.4.5 error

Tags: angularjs

I'm using `Angularjs` version `1.2.23` in my project, now want to upgrade it to `1.4.5` , but an errors occur During upgrade as mentioned below. my questions are:

Can i do that?

Or:

Firstly change it to 1.3 afterwards to 1.4 ?!

My error:

```
[$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

Answer (score 1):

You should follow migration guides, because there are a lot of stuff changed from 1.2 to 1.4, so you should follow migration step from 1.2 to 1.3 and then from 1.3 to 1.4

Check this page for the guides: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration